# How to enhance existing configuration with custom gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm new to implementing custom gradle plugins. What I want is to enhance the properties of another plugin If I find that it has been applied with some extra values from my custom gradle plugin.

For example lets assume that on *Project A* I apply my custom plugin named *customPlugin*. I want my `customPlugin` to detect if `sonarqube` is configured and on the existing sonarqube clojure congifured to add additional properties **prior** the sonarqume task is executed, is this possible?

for instance I have the following clojure somewhere in my build.gradle

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectName", "${project.name}"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "${project.group}:${project.name}"
    }
}
```

and I want my plugin to inject property:

```
property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:3456"
```

I want to do this in way so as task `sonarqube` contains all properties both the initials and ones injected by my custom plugin

so far I try to detect if a plugin is applied with the following way:

```
@Override
void apply(Project project) {
  if (project.plugins.hasPlugin(org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubePlugin)) {
    // sonarqube is here
  }
}
```

the thing is that if this is imported from another file (`apply from: 'gradle/sonar.gradle'`) it is not recognized but if it is on the same file it is better recognized

what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried `project.plugins.withType(SonarQubePlugin) { ... do stuff ... }`. That should work however the plugin is applied, the callback should be fired?

Comment: @tim_yates thnks for the tip I will try it and share results

Comment: @tim_yates I get the SonarQubePlugin instance but how to I enhance the configuration?